Power BI: Why does LookupValue return blank?
Problem: My LookupValue function returns blank value in my Matrix on a page containing a slicer. However, for validation purposes, if I create a new page and matrix and add the LookupValue measure there, it works fine.
There is the Slicer and Matrix on the page 1, and I want to add this second Matrix to it because it relates to the data on that page.
What I'm trying to do: In the first image below, the slicer is filtering a table to display the Source Channel and Destination Channel relationship based upon the slicer filtering on the Source value. What I want to do is add the 2nd Matrix to display like details on the Destination Channel as well so it is all on the first page, and use the lookup to display those. Again, this works on a separate page, but not on the page with the slicer, the lookup returns blank.
What is involved: There are two tables involved. ALL_CHANNELS1 and ALL_ROUTES1. ALL_ROUTES returns the Source > Destination detail of the first Matrix. The 2nd matrix includes a "Selected Destination" Measure created referencing the Destination to also use in passing the value to the LookupValue (except I hardcoded to test in the 2nd page matrix - see 2nd image). The LookupValue involves using the Selected Destination as a string value to filter on the other tables to return the correct Dest Path value. However, as I said, it returns blank on the first.
Code: Not exactly the way one would code to return a result, this is an experimental code.
Dest Path =  VAR theChannel = LOOKUPVALUE(ALL_CHANNELS1[Key],ALL_CHANNELS1[Channel Name],"DUMMY-DESTINATION") RETURN theChannel
The first page with the slicer, 1st matrix and the 2nd I would like to add the lookup.

The second 'test' page to validate my measure actually can pull the value, which I would like to do on the first, passing the "Selected Destination" value in as the value to be used in looking up the Dest Path.

